# MPMoviePlayerController in iOS 8 navigationBar remain visible after exiting Full Screen

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller

For playing Video I am using `MPMoviePlayerController`,my app supports only portrait mode but For playing Video I need to support Landscape too. Every thing is working fine till iOS 7.x. In iOS 8.0, After exiting Full screen there remains a navigation bar. Please refer below image.

In App delegate, under `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow`, following is used.

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (self.forceLandscapeRight) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }    
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}
```

Noe in my controller class for initiating MPMoviePlayerController:

```
    [self.mpMoviePlayerContr setContentURL:object];
    [theMoviPlayer prepareToPlay];
    self.mpMoviePlayerContr.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    self.mpMoviePlayerContr.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    [self.mpMoviePlayerContr play];
    self.mpMoviePlayerContr.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.mpMoviePlayerContr.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [theMoviPlayer setFullscreen:false animated:YES];
```

Also, I have some notification for entering and exiting Full screen.

```
- (void) moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    ED_APPDelegate.forceLandscapeRight = YES;
    [self.mpMoviePlayerContr setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [self.mpMoviePlayerContr play];
}

- (void) moviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    ED_APPDelegate.forceLandscapeRight = NO;
    [self.mpMoviePlayerContr setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
    [self.mpMoviePlayerContr play];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    ED_APPDelegate.forceLandscapeRight = NO;
    if (currentOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||currentOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight ) {
        [self.mpMoviePlayerContr setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
        [self.mpMoviePlayerContr play];
        ED_APPDelegate.forceLandscapeRight = YES;
    } else {
        if (self.mpMoviePlayerContr.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused) {
            [self.mpMoviePlayerContr play];
        }
        [self.mpMoviePlayerContr setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
        ED_APPDelegate.forceLandscapeRight = NO;
    }

}
```

Above code is working fine in iOS 7.x, but have issue in iOS 8.0.[image]